# Windows: File rename and directory iteration clash

Tags: c++, windows, boost, filesystems

I'm using boost::filesystem to rename a file like this:

```
boost::filesystem::rename(tmpFileName, targetFile);
```

tmpFileName / targetFile are of type boost::filsystem::path.

While doing this, I iterate over the directory using this code in another thread:

```
directory_iterator end_itr;
for (directory_iterator itr(dirInfoPath); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
{
    path currentPath = itr->path();
    if (is_directory(itr->status()))
    {
        // skip directories
    }
    else 
    {
        std::string file_name = currentPath.leaf();
        if (!boost::algorithm::starts_with(file_name, "new") 
            && !boost::algorithm::starts_with(file_name, "finished")
            && boost::algorithm::ends_with(file_name, ".info"))
            {
                // save found filename in some variable
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

When this code is executed, I get an exception while renaming:

```
boost::filesystem::rename: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Is it possible that the iteration and the rename operation clash, because they both access the directory inode, or do I have some other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code you provided doesn't contain any file open operations, so it cannot `lock` the file. you iterate over `directory` and renaming `file`, right? so it's possible this file is really used by *another* application like file viewer or something else, it's quite typical error. or you have it opened in your app somewhere else